# Circular Import Problem using Statistics module

Tags: python, module, statistics, attributeerror, circular-dependency

I'm trying to run a code to figure out some statistics using the statistics module. I got to this problem about circular imports. I don't know what it is and how I can fix it.

```
 #Statistics

import statistics

numbers = []
num_of_num = input('''How many numbers are in your list?
                    *Put a whole number, otherwise the command won't run the way you want it to*''')

for i in range(int(num_of_num)):
    if i == 0:
        number = input('What is your first number?')
    else:
        number = input('What is your next number?')

    numbers.append(float(number))

statistics.mean(numbers)
statistics.median(numbers)
statistics.multimode(numbers)
min(numbers)
max(numbers)
max(numbers) - min(numbers)
sum(numbers)
```

I got this error:

```
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'statistics' has no attribute 'mean' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I'm pretty sure the Statistics module has the mean attribute, so I don't know how to fix it and what I did wrong.

Comment: What is your current file name?

Comment: It's called statistics.py

Comment: Change it to something else.

Comment: What's wrong with the name?

Comment: It has the same name as the statistics module in the python standard library, so the import function tries to import your file instead of the file in the standard library.  (This is known as "shadowing")

Comment: Thank you! It finally worked for me!